# 'deno-init' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, cmd, project, init, deno

I have installed Deno on Windows10. This is the Deno version I see in CMD:

```
deno --version
deno 1.16.3 (release, x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
v8 9.7.106.5
typescript 4.4.2
```

When I try `deno-init -y --name backend` it gives me this error message:

> 'deno-init' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: deno-init is a [third-party module](https://deno.land/x/init@v1.5.3) that needs to be installed first, see [Quickstart](https://deno.land/x/init@v1.5.3#quickstart)

Comment: @jps: You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://deno.land/x/init@v1.5.3#installation), first run deno install to install deno-init:

```
deno install --allow-read --allow-run=git --allow-write -n deno-init https://deno.land/x/init@v1.5.2/mod.ts
```

> You can install deno-init from a GitHub raw URL with a tag as well, or
> without one to get the latest and greatest (though also unreleased)
> version:

```
deno install --allow-read --allow-run=git --allow-write -n deno-init https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GJZwiers/deno-init/main/mod.ts
To
```